# NodeJS- ExpressJS mongoose API POST Request with foreign key

Tags: json, node.js, api, express, mongoose

I'm trying to create an REST API in JSON. I have 2 models, an business and an address. An Address is part of a business

When I try to create a POST request with the following JSON

```
{
    "name" :"GRIT",
    "adress":
        {
         "street" : "test",
         "number": "5",
         "city":"leuven",
         "postalcode":"2900",
         "country":"BEL"
        }
}
```

I get the following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": {
            "adress": {
                "message": "Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"{ id: 5ad8b5e4ac4b1a443877bfc2,\n  street: 'test',\n  number: '5',\n  city: 'leuven',\n  postalcode: '2900',\n  country: 'BEL' }\" at path \"adress\"",
                "name": "CastError",
                "stringValue": "\"{ id: 5ad8b5e4ac4b1a443877bfc2,\n  street: 'test',\n  number: '5',\n  city: 'leuven',\n  postalcode: '2900',\n  country: 'BEL' }\"",
                "kind": "ObjectID",
                "value": {
                    "id": "5ad8b5e4ac4b1a443877bfc2",
                    "street": "test",
                    "number": "5",
                    "city": "leuven",
                    "postalcode": "2900",
                    "country": "BEL"
                },
                "path": "adress",
                "reason": {
                    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ id: 5ad8b5e4ac4b1a443877bfc2,\n  street: 'test',\n  number: '5',\n  city: 'leuven',\n  postalcode: '2900',\n  country: 'BEL' }\" at path \"adress\"",
                    "name": "CastError",
                    "stringValue": "\"{ id: 5ad8b5e4ac4b1a443877bfc2,\n  street: 'test',\n  number: '5',\n  city: 'leuven',\n  postalcode: '2900',\n  country: 'BEL' }\"",
                    "kind": "ObjectId",
                    "value": {
                        "id": "5ad8b5e4ac4b1a443877bfc2",
                        "street": "test",
                        "number": "5",
                        "city": "leuven",
                        "postalcode": "2900",
                        "country": "BEL"
                    },
                    "path": "adress"
                }
            }
        },
        "_message": "Business validation failed",
        "message": "Business validation failed: adress: Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"{ id: 5ad8b5e4ac4b1a443877bfc2,\n  street: 'test',\n  number: '5',\n  city: 'leuven',\n  postalcode: '2900',\n  country: 'BEL' }\" at path \"adress\"",
        "name": "ValidationError"
    }
}
```

These are my mongoose models

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const businessSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    adress:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Adress',
        required:true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Business', businessSchema);

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const adressSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    street:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    number:{
        type: int,
        required: true
    },
    city:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    postalCode:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    country:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Adress', adressSchema);
```

The following is my Post request

```
//POST -> Register a business
router.post('/',function(req,res){



    const business = new Business({
        id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        adress:{
            id:new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            street: req.body.adress.street,
            number: req.body.adress.number,
            city: req.body.adress.city,
            postalcode: req.body.adress.postalcode,
            country:req.body.adress.country
        }

    });


    business
        .save()
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.status(201).json({
              message: "Business created"
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
              error: err
            });
          });



});


module.exports = router;
```

What did I do wrong? Does the adress doesn't save or do I link the two models wrong with eachother

I am using MongoDB as a Datbase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#saving-refs).

You are trying to set a `ObjectId` property with an `Adress` object. What you have to do is first save your `adress` object, and then reference it inside your  `business` object.

PS: You should name your ids as `_id` since thats the convention used in MongoDB.

It would look something like this:

```
let adress = new Adress({
  _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
  street: req.body.adress.street,
  number: req.body.adress.number,
  city: req.body.adress.city,
  postalcode: req.body.adress.postalcode,
  country: req.body.adress.country
});

adress
  .save()
  .then(() => {
    let business = new Business({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      name: req.body.name,
      adress: adress._id
    });

    business
      .save()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(201).json({
          message: "Business created"
        });
      });
  });
```